# Scala: Type missing parameter type for expanded function The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)

Tags: scala, anonymous-function, anonymous-types

I wrote a function which returns a function based on the String argument it receives. The code looks as follow:

```
def getFunction(str:String) : Map[String, String] => String={
    val s = str.charAt(0).toString()
    s matches {
      case "x" => (arg:Map[String, String]) => arg("random")
      case _ =>(arg:Map[String, String]) => arg("")
    }
  }
```

This is giving a compilation exception

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
missing parameter type for expanded function The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5) Expected type was: String   line 9 Scala Problem.
```

I looked into:
[The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869251/the-argument-types-of-an-anonymous-function-must-be-fully-known-sls-8-5).

But could understand the solution. Can anyone explain what is wrong with above code.

Thanks

Comment: The only thing that seems incorrect about your function is that you use `matches` (regex pattern matching, returns boolean) function instead of `match` keyword (structural pattern matching).

Comment: Oops .. Thanks .. It worked :)