# Avro4s: The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)

Tags: scala, avro4s

I am trying to map the fields of a case class using the [avro4s FieldMapper](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s#field-mapping).

```
implicit val short: FieldMapper = {
  case "fieldName1" => "fieldName2"
}
```

But I'm receiving the following error:

```
Error:(20, 39) missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: com.sksamuel.avro4s.FieldMapper
    implicit val short: FieldMapper = {
```

I found similar questions related to this error:

- [Scala: Type missing parameter type for expanded function The
  argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS
  8.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345561/scala-type-missing-parameter-type-for-expanded-function-the-argument-types-of-a)
- [Scala missing parameter type for expanded function The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS
  8.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53488800/scala-missing-parameter-type-for-expanded-function-the-argument-types-of-an-anon)
- [The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869251/the-argument-types-of-an-anonymous-function-must-be-fully-known-sls-8-5)

However I could not derive a solution for my particular problem.

Any help is appreciated!